# Edits which only change the edit summary should be accepted during grace period

Tags: feature-request, edits, grace-period, edit-summary

There is a five minute grace period after an edit where all edits from the same user are merged into one. Technically, you're still editing the "edit" that you previously submitted. In doing so, even the edit summary can be edited.

However, if you do not change the body, title, or tags of the question, and only change the edit summary, the edit is not applied at all. This becomes a problem when I sometimes forget to explain my edit in the edit summary. To be able to change the edit summary I have to make some other unnecessary change.

**I'm requesting that edits which only change the edit summary be accepted during grace period**

Comment: Someone asked [the same thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79180/164403) on the Overmeta nearly four years ago (they're still waiting).

Comment: @Makoto SO rules put those `two different things` together. I had to think about making unnoticable change in order the change in my summary could be recognized.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand a bit more.  So you're talking from the perspective of the OP who is editing their own post, then?

Comment: @Makoto Why only OP? Any poser can edit his post. It can edit even sombody else's post. This is called "reviewing". Anybody who edits any posts may need to update his edit.

Comment: While I agree with this feature-request one could say that you should be paying more attention before hitting the submit button. Take your time, don't rush it.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ Have you ever had your pending edit ruined by someone making a smaller, partly incompatible edit in the meantime? I've been through this enough times to know not to waste too much time pondering an edit I've made. Not to mention that sometimes, the most pre-&con- cise summary only occurs to me once I've submitted.

Comment: @Angew That's why I said I **agreed** with the request, the other part was because the OP stated that *I sometimes forget to explain my edit*.

Comment: A workaround would be to add `<!---->` somewhere int the post when you change the edit summary.

Comment: You should add `<!-- Oh almighty omnipotent all seeing and amazingly well styled stack overflow gods. I, your humble servant, really wanted to just edit the edit summary of my edit to explain why I choose these particular edits because I was worried the next editor might misunderstand the edits and re-edit my edits. In your infinite wisdom, won't let me edit the edit summary without changing content so then here is a content change as an offering to you dear SOG. May thy lines always end with semicolons. PS: Tell Lisa I said "Hi" -->`

Comment: Being able to edit a field, hitting the save button, getting no visual feedback and realizing afterwards that the changes weren't saved is a terrible user experience IMO. Is anyone willing to look into this feature request?

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround, if you can manage two additional edits within the grace period:

1. Click `[edit]`, make your necessary changes to the Edit Summary, add a `.` to the end of the post (or anything else that's easily reversible), and click `[Save Edits]`
2. Click `[edit]`, remove the `.` at the end of the post, and click `[Save Edits]` again

This will save your changes to the Edit Summary without making any unnecessary changes to the initial edit within the grace period.

Comment: You could also just insert an HTML comment, which would ensure that nothing breaks even if you fail to remove your edit.

Comment: @CodyGray Or just a trailing newline at the end of the post. Won't affect how it's rendered but is enough to count as a change.

Comment: An HTML comment has the benefit of being more than the mandatory 6 characters if the user is suggesting edits.