# Quickly following an edit with another merges their content but not the description

Tags: bug, edits, edit-summary

I have noticed this behavior a couple of times now:

If we edit something immediately after another edit, the content changes made in the later is merged with the previous (a single edit remains in history).

For example, I edited this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38139975/2333214) to remove the stack snippet, and before entering the edit description I accidentally pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> (I think) and the edit was made with the default description:

> deleted 128 characters in body

So I immediately edited the post again and added a description along the lines of:

> Replaced the snippet with code block since there is nothing to demo

Now, this edit is successful (No errors shown), but still the description `deleted 128 characters in body` is displayed.

So what happened to my meaningful sentence? Is it stored somewhere in the DB?

Expected behavior: Since the content changes of a newer edit is applied on top of the previous edit, the description should be updated too.

Comment: That's a bid odd - have you got examples of others? (I have updated the edit summary for this post as yes - your sentence is far more informative than the 128 chars removed stuff....)

Comment: This also happened to me. Do an edit, accidentally hit Enter, re-edit to add a meaningful sentence but it is ignored. My guess is it's because the second edit doesn't actually edit the question.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313440/2675154

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, edits that only change the summary are not saved. Maybe because doing so doesn't make sense if you're not in the grace period for an earlier edit, and the code doesn't bother checking?

You must make some change to the other parts of the post in order for your updated summary to be saved.

The good news is, there's a simple workaround: when you need to change the summary, also make a dummy edit that you don't intend to keep. Something small and simple like an extra comma works fine (and should prevent anyone noticing/caring for the next few seconds). Submit that edit, and the summary will be saved. Now, quickly edit a third time and undo the superfluous bit that you just changed. Submit that, and voilà: the original edit is intact with the summary that you added after the fact.

Comment: Yes this works .~.