# "Leave comment on rollback" not working?

Tags: support, rollbacks, edit-summary

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230748/lua-c-api-how-to-traverse-a-table-with-no-possibility-of-lua-error-lua-panic) just now. A user retagged it, and I rolled back the retag.

I tried to add a comment/reason for the rollback as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271924/leave-comment-when-rolling-back-an-edit/271926#271926).

My comment was:

> In the [lua] tag, common practice is to use the tags [C] or [C++] additionally for questions relating to programming the C api. [lua] is used commonly used alone for questions about the lua programming language.

But it seems like my edits to the rollback that add a comment "don't work" and are ignored by the system, and instead I only see the summary "Rollback to revision one". Also the edit time is not updated, it still says last edit was 6 minutes ago. So I assume that the system is ignoring my rollback comment.

What am I doing wrong, or is there something I didn't understand?

Comment: Did you click "rollback" or "edit"?

Comment: I clicked rollback first, then edit to edit the comment into the rollback

Comment: If you don't make any other change to the question, the summary change you entered on the "rollback revision" will be lost. A way to do a rollback with a custom message is described here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271924/leave-comment-when-rolling-back-an-edit

Comment: @Matt: That's the one that I linked. I think I understand now -- basically the issue is that I cannot leave a message if I'm only rolling back a retag? It has to actually change the post's text content? I guess that is what random said but I didn't understand at first

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. Random said it in his last sentence, yes. You are actually trying to edit the *edit summary*. A change to the *edit summary* is only applied if the post itself gets changed as well. Try to change only the edit summary of any other post within the grace period and it won't work due to the same reason. A feature to make this possible has been requested in the past ([on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313440/5024726) and [on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79180/298845))...

Comment: Incidentally, the retagging was correct; neither of those tags should be there. The C++ _definitely_ shouldn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's sometimes relevant in these C Api questions whether you are using C++, because lua can be compiled as C or C++ and it detects this with macros and behaves differently depending on which is the case. So people often ask which way you are doing it esp. when error handling is related. I agree that it turned out not to be relevant in this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per [Could we be permitted to provide a reason for rolling back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41953) you need to click the "edit" link
on the revision you want to go back to. Then you can enter a custom message and save that.

Clicking "rollback" will automatically fill in the message. And if you then try to just enter a new change reason, nothing will happen unless you also change the post content itself.

Comment: I tried editing the original revision (the one I want to go back to) instead as you suggested. (Although I find that counterintuitive, that means my comment would appear chronologically before the thing I am rolling back?) I seem to get the same results -- i.e. no response from the system. But maybe it will just take it some time to get into the database or something?

Comment: No, it would be instant

Comment: Now's the time when you awkwardly inform me "I'm sorry, you were recently placed on a secret government watchlist for potential subversive activity. You can no longer make collect calls, automatic doors will no longer open for you, and you can no longer leave rollback comments on stackoverflow."